# Android Kotlin - Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Tags: android, kotlin

I found couple of answers for this but I don't understand what the hell they are talking about and what to do in my case.

This is the code:

```
Functions().(prefs!!.getLong("userid", 0), prefs!!.getString("notifToken", "")!!)
```

I get `Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)` for `prefs!!.getString("notifToken", "")!!`

And in Functions class:

```
fun lastOnline(userid: Long, token: String){

    val params = RequestParams()
    params.put("userid", userid)
    params.put("token", token)

    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.post("https://www.bla.com/do.php", params, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, response: JSONArray?)
        {

        }
        override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, e: Throwable, response: JSONArray?)
        {
            Log.d("pikabo", "error")
        }
    })
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code boils down to `Functions().()`, and that does not make a lot of sense. `Functions()` will create an instance of your `Functions` class. But then you seem to be missing a function name after the `.`.

I am going to guess that you are trying to call `lastOnline()`, in which case you need to use that function name:

```
Functions().lastOnline(prefs!!.getLong("userid", 0), prefs!!.getString("notifToken", "")!!)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all looks good and still same error occurs pls check if there is any hidden character in the lines of code typed/pasted

Comment: I re-write my line with same error and voila it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the excess `!!` because it will never be `null` with a default value passed into.